# Sort labeled dataset with labels in separate csv file?

Tags: python

I have a dataset of ~3500 images, with the labels of each image in a csv file. The csv file has two columns: the first one contains the exact name of the image file (i.e. 00001.jpg) and the second column contains the label of the image. There are a total of 7 different labels.

How can I sort the images from one huge folder to 7 different folders (each image in its respective category) in an efficient manner? Does anyone have a script that can do this?

Also, is there any way I can do this with Google Drive? I've already uploaded the dataset to Drive in order to use with Colab soon, so I don't want to have to do it again (takes ~2.5 hours).

Comment: That's a tiny data set. This sounds more like an OS issue. Are you copying or moving the files?

Comment: What do you mean by copying or moving? i.e. manually sorting the dataset?

Comment: If you move a file, it should be negligible because it simply relocates the file into the correct subfolder without having to do anything to the file contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about performance, probably there are better ways...
But this would be my take on the problem:
(not tested, so might need small adjustments)

I'm assuming the images are in a subfolder `/images/`, but the csv and the script are in root. Furthermore I'm assuming the csv is named `images.csv` and the columns in the csv are titled `file` and `label`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import os

df = pf.DataFrame.from_csv('images.csv')

for _, row in df.iterrows():
  f = row['file']
  l = row['label']
  os.replace(f'images/{f}', f'images/{l}/{f}')
```

I don't know what google drive would make out of it, but as long as you can run it on a google-drive-synced folder, I wouldn't know why this should be an issue.

**Note:** if you test it, you may want to do so on a copy of the files, in case I screwed up...